# List or Tuple without Brackets not for printing

Tags: python

Im trying to make a bot using **pyautogui**. Im saving some important pixel with x , y location. There are some game cards on that locations. But I cant use them. Im using click funtion to click but i dont want to enter position everytime, i want to use same pixel location. Any help or idea appreciated.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
    resimler = []
    card1x = (833, 958, 1083)
    card1y = (477, 622)
    card2x =(809, 909, 1009, 1109)
    card2y =(493, 609)
    card3x =(833, 960, 1087)
    card3y =(292, 464, 636, 808)
    card4x =(809, 909, 1009, 1109)
    card4y =(310, 470, 630, 790)
    card5x =(809, 909, 1009, 1109)
    card5y =(286, 418, 550, 682, 814)
    cards =((card1x[0], card1y[0]),(card1x[1],card1y[0]),(card1x[2],card1y[0]),(card1x[0],card1y[1]),(card1x[1],card1y[1]),(card1x[2],card1y[1]),(card2x[0],card2y[0]),(card2x[1],card2y[0]),(card2x[2],card2y[0]),(card2x[3],card2y[0]),(card2x[0],card2y[1]),(card2x[1],card2y[1]),(card2x[2],card2y[1]),(card2x[3],card2y[1]))
```

When i print this, its printing

```
print(cards[5])
```

#(100,200)
but i need numbers for click funtion like this 100,200

Btw I will use like this

```
    i=0
    
    def click(x,y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    
    def list_islem(color):
        global i
        images.append(color)
        if colorin images[:-1]:
            print("bulundu")
            click(cards[images.index(color)])
            click(cards[i])
            images.pop(images.index(color))
            images.pop()
            i-=1
            print(images)
        else:
            print("bulunamadı")
            print(images)
            i+=1
```

when i use list_islem function i got this error

```
bulunamadı
[255]
bulundu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gungor\Desktop\n11\bot.py", line 67, in <module>
    list_islem(b)
  File "C:\Users\Gungor\Desktop\n11\bot.py", line 44, in list_islem
    click(cards[resimler.index(renk)])
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your question? What exactly is not working? Got any error logs?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  "Doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're looking for the `*` tuple unpacking operator? Try the following

```
click(*cards[i]) # Using Tuple Unpacking
click(cards[i][0], cards[i][1]) # Which is equivalent to this
```